# Change Text on Landscape mode with Java Code and not XML (Android)

Tags: android

I wrote my layout entirely in java code because  it was just more convenient. (I had a lot of `textViews` and using `for` statements were more convenient).

However, my TextViews require the day of the week and in portrait mode, I would like to cut the day of the week to a short form. For example, I want "Sunday" to show "Sun" for portrait mode, but "Sunday" for landscape mode.

I understand how to do this in XML files, but how do I do it in code?

I.e. sample code:

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
parent.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
TextView example = new TextView;
example.setLayoutParams(mparams);
example.setText("Sunday"); //<--make this "Sun" when in portrait but "Sunday" in landscape
parent.addView(example);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is getting restarted when it moves to landscape then you can define the strings that need to be expanded in Landscape mode in `values-land`

And it is never a good idea to use hard coded strings. Even if you are creating layouts programmatically use strings.xml to store strings

Answer (score 1):

You can override the **onConfigurationChanged()** method in your Activity class, and you can set your text, when orientation will change this method will call... Hope it will helpful to you..:)

```
       @Override
       public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // Here you can set text **Sun**
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //Here you can set text **Sunday**
        }

    }
```

Comment: THat looks like it will help, but I should elaborate. My Layout is in a class and I did that so that I could make multiple similiar layouts quickly. Will that code work within an instantiated object?